# Consulta con PHP PDO y SQLServer

Tags: php, sql-server, mvc

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta con `PHP` a una base de datos en `SQLServer` con `ajax` y `MVC` pero cuando ejectuto la consulta me arroja el siguiente error

```
sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\Personal\modelos\usuarios.modelo.php</b> on line <b>49</b><br />
```

Esta es la manera en que envio el input por medio de `JS` al fichero de ajax

```
var validarUsuarioRepetido = false;
var rutaOculta = $("#rutaOculta").val();

$("#password").change(function(){
  var usuarioPassword = $('#password').val();
  var datos = new FormData();
  datos.append("validarUsuario", usuarioPassword);

  $.ajax({
    url: rutaOculta+"ajax/usuarios.ajax.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: datos,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(respuesta){
      $("#user").val(respuesta);
      console.log(respuesta);
    }
  })
})
```

posteriormente el ajax lo recibe de la siguiente manera y lo envia al controlador

```
<?php

require_once "../controladores/usuarios.controlador.php";
require_once "../modelos/usuarios.modelo.php";

class AjaxUsuarios{
  /**
   * Validar Usuario
  **/
  public $validarUsuario;

  public function ajaxValidarUsuario(){
      $datos = $this->validarUsuario;
      $respuesta = ControladorUsuarios::ctrMostrarUsuarioP($datos);
      echo ($respuesta);
  }

}

/**
 * Validar Usuario
 **/
if (isset($_POST["validarUsuario"])){
    $valUsuario = new AjaxUsuarios();
    $valUsuario -> validarUsuario = $_POST["validarUsuario"];
    $valUsuario -> ajaxValidarUsuario();
}
```

Cuando el controlador lo recibe lo envia al modelo para generar la consulta y retornarlo

```
static public function mdlMostrarUsuarioP($tabla, $datos){
    $serverName = "SERVIDOR"; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"BASEDEDATOS", "UID"=>"USUARIO", "PWD"=>"PSSWORD");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

      $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE CB_ID_NUM=?";
      $stmt1 = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, array($datos));
      $result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt1);
      return $stmt3 = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result);
    }
```

y al momento en que entra al sqlsrv_fetch_array es donde me arroja el error antes mencionado, espero alguien pueda ayudarme, es la primera vez que intento generar la conexion y una consulta con `SQLServer`

Comment: `$result` no es un conjunto de resultados como esperas, sino que es `FALSE` porque algo falla en tu consulta, puede ser la conexión que es nula, o puede ser algún error de sintaxis en la consulta o en la preparación de la misma. Puedes capturar los errores adecuadamente como muestra el [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php).

Answer (score 1):

Te propongo este código que controla todas las eventualidades. Cuando haya errores, creará una clave `error` dentro del array `$data`.

En el destino puedes probar los datos haciendo un `print_r($data)`. Para determinar los errores, puedes buscar la clave `error` dentro del array resultante.

```
public static function mdlMostrarUsuarioP($tabla, $datos){
    $serverName = "SERVIDOR"; //serverName\instanceName
    $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"BASEDEDATOS", "UID"=>"USUARIO", "PWD"=>"PSSWORD");
    $msgError=FALSE;
    if ( $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo) ){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE CB_ID_NUM=?";
        if ( $stmt = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $sql, array($datos)) ) {
            if ( $result = sqlsrv_execute($stmt) ) {
                $data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
            } else {
                $msgError="Error ejecutando la consulta: ";
            }
        } else {
            $msgError="Error preparando la consulta: ";
        }
    } else {
        $msgError="Conexión no disponible: ";
    }
    if ($msgError){
        $errors = sqlsrv_errors();
        $data["error"]=$msgError.$error[ 'message'];
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Intente realizar los cambios como me comentaste, pero el error sigue siendo el mismo sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: @cesg.dav es que hay una diferencia con el modo usual. El conjunto de resultados es devuelto cuando de ejecuta `prepare`, por lo tanto hay que corregir poniéndolo así: **`$data = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt);
`** De ese modo debería funcionar.